# PyPlot bar crashes with Log=True

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to do a simple logarithmic bar plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.bar(range(10), [4**i for i in range(10)], log=True)
plt.show()
```

It crashes with:

```
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2383, in bar


 ret = ax.bar(left, height, width=width, bottom=bottom, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 4903, in bar
    self.add_patch(r)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 1572, in add_patch
    self._update_patch_limits(p)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 1590, in _update_patch_limits
    xys = patch.get_patch_transform().transform(vertices)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\patches.py", line 582, in get_patch_transform
    self._update_patch_transform()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\patches.py", line 578, in _update_patch_transform
    bbox = transforms.Bbox.from_bounds(x, y, width, height)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 786, in from_bounds
    return Bbox.from_extents(x0, y0, x0 + width, y0 + height)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

When I use log=False, it works. I treid plt.yscale('log'), but then the bars disappeared. I'dont see, how I could use the log Parameter wrong in such a simple case.

Comment: It works for me on matplotlib 1.2.0 and python 2.7.3

Comment: I can reproduce your error with matplotlib 1.2.1, but not with 1.3.0

Comment: Also tested on matplotlib 1.3.0 and python 3.3.0 (MacOSX), and works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in your version of matplotlib. While the default for the parameter `bottom` of `plt.bar` is claimed to be `0`, adding an extra keyword argument sets `bottom=None` which subsequently leads to arithmetic using `bottom` to fail.

As a workaround you can set `bottom` yourself to the default value again.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.arange(10)
plt.bar(x, 4**x, bottom=0, log=True)
plt.show()
```